# Why there is little improvement after including the predictors in logistic regression?

Tags: regression, logistic

I'm working on a project on prediction of at-risk students using logistic regression. I'm new to this analysis, so I need some help to clarify some issues:

1. Should I code "return" student as 1 or "drop-out" student as 1 in the analysis (My purpose is to spot at-risk student)?
2. After I ran the analysis, I found almost no improvement concerning percentage of correct rate in the classification table between baseline model and model with predictors. (There is a significant difference, though.) Does this mean the predictors did not contribute much to discriminate the two groups? If my purpose is to find a parsimonious model, what standard(s) should I take?

Comment: What the class balance between drop-out and return? With what metric and cross-validation strategy are you evaluating your model? Are these predictors models? What subset of the data are they trained on? Have you tried a nonlinear model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "classification rate" is a highly arbitrary and insensitive measure.  It's best to avoid this index.  Judge predictive discrimination by the log likelihood, the generalized $R^2$ derived from it, Somers' $D_{xy}$ rank correlation between predicted and observed, the $c$-index (ROC area) derived from $D_{xy}$, and the Brier score.

Comment: Thank you so much, Frank! Your answer really helps! Could you elaborate more on how to use those statistics to compare models with different predictors? In other words, how can I get a most parsimonious model with higher prediction rate? Thank you!!!

Comment: It is not good to seek a parsimonous model because that causes multiplicity problems, overfitting, and noise.  It is best to formulate the model using subject matter expertise and not being data-driven (at least limiting how much the data drive the model specification).

Comment: I see. Thank you so much, Frank!!! One more thing, if I want to compare different models, which statistic(s) would you recommend to use in order to get a "best" model?

Comment: The idea of a "best" model is probably one you want to discard. As George Box said "all models are wrong but some are useful". Also, parsimony and prediction are generally opposing forces.

Comment: Thank you, Peter! If my goal is to find a model that is able to have high prediction, any thoughts on how to attain that?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding 1. It doesn't matter, really, it's just a matter of which is easier to interpret. They answer the same question (it's like the difference between "Is Joe taller than Mary?" and "Is Mary taller than Joe?")

Regarding 2. Impossible to tell without more information. T[his post](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/)  on my blog may help you improve your question.

Comment: Thank you so much, Peter! I appreciate your input! If I want to find a parsimonious model to have correct prediction results, what strategy should I take? (Using what statistics to compare...)Thank you!!!